# Java: Data structure for caching computation result?

Tags: java, caching, dictionary, tuples, computation

I have an expensive computation, the result of which I'd like to cache. Is there some way to make a map with two keys? I'm thinking of something like `Map<(Thing1, Thing2), Integer>`.

Then I could check:

```
if (! cache.contains(thing1, thing2)) {
  return computeResult();
}
else {
  return cache.getValue(thing1, thing2);
}
```

pseudocode. But something along those lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a class that holds Thing1 and Thing2, e.g:

```
class Things {
    public final Thing1 thing1;
    public final Thing2 thing2;
    public Things(Thing1 thing1, Thing2 thing2) {
      this.thing1 = thing1; 
      this.thing2 = thing2;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) { ... }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() { ... };
 }
```

Then to use it:

```
Things key = new Things(thing1, thing2);
if (!cache.contains(key) {
    Integer result = computeResult();
    cache.put(key, result);
    return result;
} else {
    return cache.getValue(key);
}
```

Note you have to implement equals and hashcode to make this code work properly. If you need this code to be thread-safe then have a look at ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Eerie.. I *just* did this five minutes ago, then came on SO and saw this questions...  I'd recommend this implementation of the hashCode method (which is just the default eclipse implementation): `return (31 + thing1.hashCode())*31 + thing2.hashCode();`

Comment: @Kip: Actually, I'd recommend using `HashCodeBuilder`, `EqualsBuilder`, and `CompareToBuilder` from Apache Commons Lang. :-)

Comment: It took me <10 minutes to implement this, and now my program runs in 25% of the time. Wow.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want memoisation. The latest trunk head of [Functional Java](http://code.google.com/p/functionaljava) has a memoising product type `P1` that models a computation whose result is cached.

You would use it like this:

```
P1<Thing> myThing = new P1<Thing>() {
  public Thing _1() {
    return expensiveComputation();
  }
}.memo();
```

Calling _1() the first time will run the expensive computation and store it in the memo. After that, the memo is returned instead.

For your "two keys", you'd want a simple pair type. Functional Java has this too in the form of the class `P2<A, B>`. To memoise such a value, simply use `P1<P2<A, B>>`.

You can also use the `Promise<A>` class instead of the memoisation. This has been in the library for a while, so you'd just need the latest binary. You would use that as follows:

```
Promise<Thing> myThing =
  parModule(sequentialStrategy).promise(new P1<Thing>() {
    public Thing _1() {
      return expensiveComputation();
    }
  });
```

To get the result out, simply call `myThing.claim()`. `Promise<A>` also provides methods for mapping functions over the result *even if the result is not yet ready*.

You need to `import static fj.control.parallel.ParModule.parModule` and `fj.control.parallel.Strategy.sequentialStrategy`. If you want the computation to run in its own thread, replace `sequentialStrategy` with one of the other strategies provided by the `Strategy` class.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/), its [`MapMaker`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) class has a `makeComputingMap` method that does exactly what you described. As a free bonus, it's also thread-safe (implements `ConcurrentMap`).

As for the two-keys thing, you will have to make a class that contains the two keys, and implement a suitable implementation of `equals`, `hashCode`, and (if applicable) `compareTo` that does the key comparison the way you want it.

Comment: I'm all for Google Collections, but I'm having a hard time understanding how this would work.

Comment: You basically create a `Function` object that calls your `computeResult` function. The Google object will take care of calling that function and caching its value, when you get the appropriate item from the map. :-)